# check type of classifier object in python cv2?

Tags: python, opencv, typechecking

How do I check that I've got a `cv2.CascadeClassifier` object in [openCV 2](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/objdetect/doc/cascade_classification.html)?
Atm, if I run it with a wrong path it won't let me know and will give me dud results. So I want this check but don't know the correct call/syntax.

**input:** 
`cascadePath = "correctPath.xml"`

```
# load the trained cascade
print("loading classifier...")
trainedCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascadePath)
```

**Try1:**

```
if type(trainedCascade) is not 'cv2.CascadeClassifier':
        print(type(trainedCascade))
        raise Exception("no classifier found at this path")
```

**Result1:**

`<type 'cv2.CascadeClassifier'>`
`Exception: no classifier found at this path`

**Try2:**

```
if not isinstance(trainedCascade, type(cv2.CascadeClassifier)):
    raise Exception("no classifier found at this path")
```

**Result2:**
`Exception: no classifier found at this path`

**Try3 [empty() method](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/objdetect/doc/cascade_classification.html):**

```
  if cv2.CascadeClassifier.empty():
        print("trained cascade is empty!")
```

**Result3:**

`AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'empty'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there:

```
if not isinstance(trainedCascade, cv2.CascadeClassifier):
```

**update:** if your getting `TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a class..`, that means that `cv2.CascadeClassifier` is not a class, but probably some sort of factory function. Depending on how opaque it's been made, you might not be able to check the returned type.  You could try:

```
if trainedCascade.empty():
```

Comment: i did try that too. but the question was getting long so i didnt include it.
but when i try that i get: `TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a class, type, or tuple of classes and types`

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem. As @thebjorn said, you could use

```
if isinstance(object, class):
```

If you are getting the error `TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a class, type, or tuple of classes and types`, you can try:

```
if isinstance(trainedCascade, type(cv2.CascadeClassifier())):
```

That way you construct an object of the desired type and then check it against your target object.